# Probability of forming an odd integer from a 5-permutation of integers in [0,9]

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My intuition is telling me that the probability of forming an odd integer from a 5-element partial permutation of integers in [0,9] is one-half, because it should be the same probability as the integer being even, which makes those probabilities one-half.

However, I'm having trouble proving it.

I split the problem into five disjoint cases: the number consists of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 odd integers.

P(the number is odd and it uses only 1 odd integer) = $\frac{5*4*3*2*\binom{5}{1}}{10*9*8*7*6} = \frac{600}{30240}$, because the last digit must be an odd integer, and there are five candidates, therefore 5 choose 1, and the rest are even integers where the first even integer has 5 candidates, the second, 4 candidates and so on.

P(the number is odd and it uses only 2 odd integer) = $\frac{5*4*3*\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{10*9*8*7*6} = \frac{1200}{30240}$, because the last digit must be an odd integer, and there are five candidates, therefore 5 choose 1, and there is another odd integer, which has 4 possible candidates; the rest are even integers where the first even integer has 5 candidates, the second, 4 candidates and so on.

I see a problem with this approach is that I can continue to the case of 3, 4, 5, but the numerator would not add up to half of 30240. In fact, the numerator only adds up to 3720.

I feel it might be the placement of the odd integers other than the last, so I tried:

P(the number is odd and it uses only 2 odd integer) = $\frac{5*4*3*4*\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{10*9*8*7*6} = \frac{4800}{30240}$, because the last digit must be an odd integer, and there are five candidates, therefore 5 choose 1, and there is another odd integer, which has 4 possible candidates but it can be in any of the 4 places, therefore multiplied by 4; the rest are even integers where the first even integer has 5 candidates, the second, 4 candidates and so on.

But this time the numbers are too large, and it's way over half of 30240.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: All that matters is the units place.  As that can be any of the $10$ digits with equal probability, the answer is $\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, but I need to know where I went wrong with my thoughts, as this is a sub-problem of a bigger problem.

Comment: But, as you remark, your count fails to consider the possible placement of the odd digits other than requiring one to fall in the units place.  If you place the "extra" odd digits properly, it should work.  You don't include that calculation in your post so I can't tell you where your error falls.

Comment: So you can check your calculation:  If you allow for the various placements of the extra odd numbers you get numerators $(600,4800,7200,2400,120)$ which sum to $15120$ as they should.  I stress that this is not a great method.  Like many case-by-case combinatorial arguments it is quite error prone, as you will have noticed already.  And it is entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I noticed my error. I wasn't counting those correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is clear from the unit digit but if you want to still find all favorable permutations and divide by total permutations, why not do

Favorable permutations $ = \displaystyle 5 \cdot {9 \choose 4} \cdot 4!$ and then divide by $30240$.

[Explanation: choose the unit digit from $5$ odd digits and then choose $4$ from remaining $9$ digits and permute them]

**Even if we go by your method, it should be**

Count of odd integers with only one odd digit (unit place)  = $\displaystyle 5 \cdot {5 \choose 4} \cdot 4!$

Count of odd integers with two odd digits  = $\displaystyle 5 \cdot 4 \cdot {5 \choose 3} \cdot 4!$

Count of odd integers with three odd digits  = $\displaystyle 5 \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 2} \cdot 4!$

Count of odd integers with four odd digits  = $\displaystyle 5 \cdot {4 \choose 3} \cdot {5 \choose 1} \cdot 4!$

Count of odd integers with all digits odd  = $5!$